# SED - Add URL prefix to random pdf filenames

Tags: sed, html

I have an html file I preview locally before uploading to the web. In it there are links to local pdf files. To upload, I have to prefix a web url to the pdf's.

Here is a sample of my local html file -

```
<a href="randomFilename.pdf">Article HERE</a>
```

This is how it needs to be modified for my web version -

```
<a href="https://www.site.com/folder1/folder2/randomFilename.pdf">Article HERE</a>
```

So `https://www.site.com/folder1/folder2/` needs to be added to totally random pdf filenames. I don't know if SED can do this. We can search for "pdf" but how to go backwards and add this prefix? I seached the 50 sed commands page but could not find a clue to do this.

Comment: if the HTML file and the .PDF files are on the same web site then it's best to specify only the path to the PDF files in the links, without the site name. i.e. just `/folder1/folder2/\1.pdf`. Why? Because it makes it easier to move the site to a different domain name and/or re-use the content on multiple domains (e.g. both www.example.com and just plain example.com). Also, it's generally a bad idea to just make up domain names, they may actually belong to someone (and site.com does, in fact, belong to someone). Use `example.com` (or .net or .org, etc) instead - that's what they're for.

Comment: Finally, `sed` is the wrong tool for extracting data from or modifying structured text like HTML files.  Use an XML processing tool like [xmstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or a language like python or perl with good XML libraries.   Yes, it's more complicated/harder to do, but that's because working with structured text files **is** complicated.  Not using a parser is prone to breakage when there are even minor variations in the input text that a simple regex was not written to cope with - e.g. unexpected tags or tag ordering, even spaces and newlines can break a regex-only script.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately I have to provide the full url because the html file is a "code your own" mailchimp email template for my club's newsletter and to get images/pdf's to show, mailchimp says the full url is needed, which means, yes, you are correct, the pdf's are not on mailchimp's site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing would just be to capture the filename in a capture group. With the `-E` flag to set you can use normal parentheses for this. (Or you could use `\(` and `\)` without the `-E` flag.) You can then refer back to it as `\1` in the replacement.

```
sed -E 's#<a href="([^"]*)\.pdf"#<a href="https://www.site.com/folder1/folder2/\1.pdf"#g' filename.html
```

This looks for patterns beginning with `<a href="` followed by a series of anything other than a double quote (caught in the capture group), following by `.pdf"` and replaces it with the same but with `https://www.site.com/folder1/folder2/` prior to the captured group.

I'm assuming you're always using double quotes for opening and closing the URLs and that there aren't any pdf links that already have the protocol, domain, etc. in them.

Comment: I'm getting an error with version 4.0.7 -  sed: file sedscript.sed line 1: Unknown option to `s'

Comment: Oh, I should mention I' trying to get this working on windows. I'm using a separate .sed file called from a batch file which is working well doing other sed things. I'll keep trying to use your answer in a separate .sed file. I'm using GNU version also.

Comment: OK, I got it working using the .sed file. I had to escape the parenthesis. I have found that some other lines are being processed that shouldn't be. I can narrow it down by searching "Article HERE". I will try to modify your answer and make it work.

Comment: OK, it's working great, thanks!